# Multiple entities of same hierarchy mapped to single attribute

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Assume I have the following class hiearchy:

```
/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
 class Notification {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Miroc\CoreBundle\Entity\User",    inversedBy="notifications", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
     private $user;
}

class UserNotification extends Notification
class ProjectNotification extends Notification
```

further, assume I have a User class which maps Notifications:

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Miroc\CoreBundle\Entity\Notification", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $notifications;
}
```

Now, what I would like is the following: if the user creates X UserNotifications and Y ProjectNotifications, then calling the getter for $notifications in the User class should return an array of length |X+Y| with all instances of both types. This should of course scale to other subclasses of Notification as well.

Is this possible, and if so how? The example above does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably looking for a Single Table Inheritance strategy as documented in the 
[Doctrine Docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). I think it's likely that you will have to add your own method to combine the two arrays.

It would of course be possible to have two separate entities for the two types of notification and combine them similarly but from your question I'm assuming you want them in one table.

Comment: This is correct.  See the big yellow box on the docs page Shazbot linked.  If you want a relation to the "Notifications" superclass, that class needs to be an entity.  Single-Table inheritance is probably the appropriate strategy here.